# Grep a file output from another set of grep/awk command pipe

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have a linux pipe command that gives a file output as follows,

> `grep "tsmcN" $PROJECT_CDL_INC | awk '{print $2}'`

/p/tech/n5p/tech-prerelease/v0.9.0_pre.10/tsmcN5/cdl_addon/tsmcN5.cdl

I want to further pipe this file output to grep some contents from it. But when I try this,

> `grep "tsmcN" $PROJECT_CDL_INC | awk '{print $2}'|grep dio`

<NO OUTPUT! grep didn't work! but the file has the contents to be grepped>

> `grep dio /p/tech/n5p/tech-prerelease/v0.9.0_pre.10/tsmcN5/cdl_addon/tsmcN5.cdl`

```
.SUBCKT ndio_12_mac PLUS MINUS
.SUBCKT ndio_12_ntn_mac PLUS MINUS
.SUBCKT ndio_hia12_mac PLUS MINUS
.SUBCKT ndio_hia12_ntn_mac PLUS MINUS
.SUBCKT ndio_mac PLUS MINUS
.SUBCKT pdio_12_mac PLUS MINUS
.SUBCKT pdio_hia12_mac PLUS MINUS
.SUBCKT pdio_mac PLUS MINUS
```

I know I am missing something trivial, but I couldn't find answers by myself.
Regards,
Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep "tsmcN" $PROJECT_CDL_INC | awk '{print $2}'` seems to be outputting a list of file names. You then seem to want to grep for `dio` **within** each of those files but instead you're greping in the file **names** again.

Try this:

```
awk '/tsmcN/ "$PROJECT_CDL_INC" |
xargs grep dio
```

Comment: Yes. I missed xargs proper usage. I still need to format the output but the contents are there. Thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 0):

With this command:

```
grep "tsmcN" $PROJECT_CDL_INC | awk '{print $2}'|grep dio
```

you are literally grepping the string `/p/tech/n5p/tech-prerelease/v0.9.0_pre.10/tsmcN5/cdl_addon/tsmcN5.cdl` for `dio`

If what you're asking is to take that filename and then grep that file for dio:

```
grep "tsmcN" $PROJECT_CDL_INC | cat `awk '{print $2}'` | grep dio
```